# (Java) Why can't I call on this method created? Do I not have the right parameters?

Tags: java, methods, parameters, drawing

I'm trying to work on the CS project where I have to draw a bunch of shapes using a "Turtle" library. However, When I try to call upon the method to be used, it gives me and error. I'm pretty sure it has to do with the method parameters, which I'm just learning about now and still don't usually know which to put in. Any advice?![enter image description here][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yn32y.png

Comment: Please post the code *inside the question* as text, rather than a link to an image - and include the exact error message in the question too.

Comment: It would be also helpful for you to enable line numbers, so you will be able to localize your problem better in your source code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to specify the parameter type at the method call, so remove `Turtle` from `drawRectangle(Turtle tParam)`, it should be like this - `drawRectangle(tParam)`

Comment: You should also make sure that the object you are passing is actually named tParam; if you don't have an object named tParam in your main, this method call will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The error refers to a problem in your program's code. Specifically you forgot to close a bracket somewhere.